# MySQL Order By Column1 / Column2

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT `player`,`kills`,`deaths` FROM `stats` ORDER BY `kills` DESC LIMIT 0 , 10
```

how to make ORDER BY to
THE BIGGEST value from (KILLS / DEATHS)

thanks

```
---------------------------
| player | kills | deaths |
---------------------------
| user1  | 20    | 2      | 
---------------------------
| user2  | 10    | 2      |
---------------------------
| user3  | 30    | 2      | 
---------------------------
```

KDR = Kill Death Ratio = Kills / Deaths

so the result order like this

```
1. user3 = 15

2. user1 = 10

3. user2 = 5
```

Comment: Can you add sample data and the expected result for explanation?

Comment: already update, i dont know how to make table in stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution to your problem:

```
SELECT `player`,`kills`,`deaths`,`assist`
FROM `stats`
ORDER BY (
    CASE WHEN `kills` > `deaths` THEN `kills` ELSE `deaths`
)
DESC LIMIT 0 , 10
```

The trick is to use the `CASE` statement for choosing the larger of the two columns `'kills'` or `'deaths'` for ordering the results.

Answer (score 0):

Well i guess you want also to show the k_d_ratio as a value so i would suggest this solution.

```
  SELECT `player`,`kills`,`deaths`,`assist`, ISNULL 
     (kill /(NULLIF(deaths,0), 
      99999999999) 
    as k_d_ratio FROM stats 
   ORDER BY `k_d_ratio` DESC LIMIT 0 , 10
```

Comment: How will you handle the case when `deaths` happens to be zero for a given record?

Comment: Fixed it. Now if deaths = 0 we will use null for the devision. Division with null gives a null again. If the devision gives null we set the return value to 99999999999. (Choosed it by assumtion it will always be the highst value and able to represent infinity.) Not the nicest solution but should work.